# As an Indian citizen with a U.S. permanent resident card, will I need a visa to travel from the Republic of Ireland to Northern Ireland?

Tags: visas, indian-citizens, ireland, northern-ireland, us-permanent-residents

I am a permanent resident in the USA. I have an Irish tourist visa. While in the Republic of Ireland, I would like to take a day tour to Giant's Causeway (Northern Ireland). Will I need a visa for the UK? I have applied for a multiple-entry visa for Ireland.

Comment: Are you asking whether US residence allows entry to the UK (it doesn't)? Does your Irish visa have the BIVS endorsement?

Comment: @M.Patel Have you tried using https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa

Answer (score 3):

Your US residence does not enable you to enter the UK visa free. However, you would not need a separate UK visa if your Irish Tourist Visa is endorsed with the coding *BIVS*. The British-Irish Visa Scheme allows for mutual recognition of short-stay visas between the UK and Ireland. If it does not, you would have to apply for a [UK Standard Visitor visa](https://www.gov.uk/standard-visitor-visa).